# Apache Security Headers Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to get security headers to work for my website. I'm testing via https://securityheaders.io/, but I'm getting an F. My .htaccess file is below.

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing? The only caching plugin I have is Autoptimize. I've tried disabling with the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN Block IP
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Deny from 68.228.160.63
# END Block IP

# BEGIN MODULE HEADERS
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;"
Header always set x-xss-protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
</ifModule>
# END MODULE HEADERS

# BEGIN GZIP COMPRESSION
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# END GZIP COMPRESSION

# BEGIN DEFLATE COMPRESSION
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  ### Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  ### Remove browser bugs
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</ifModule>
# END DEFLATE COMPRESSION

#BEGIN EXPIRES HEADERS
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour"
# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"
# Image files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"
# Webfonts
ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
#END EXPIRES HEADERS

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Thank you,

Comment: I'd look carefully at the capitalization of your two `<ifModule mod_headers.c>` sections, for starters. Note the different syntax highlighting versus all the others.

Comment: Good point. I put it through a .htaccess validator and it said it was alright. This one specifically - http://www.htaccesscheck.com/ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'd also check that mod_headers is installed.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue? I noticed "Header set" works for html files and other static resources but not for php files.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer ?